# Construct a continuous function $f$ over $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0) = f(1)$ but $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $0 < a < 1$ is not of the form $\dfrac{1}{n}$ for positive integer $n$. Construct a continuous function $f$ over $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0) = f(1)$ but $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$ for all $x \in [0,1-a]$.

This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668804/show-that-for-any-positive-integer-n-there-is-x-in-0-1-frac1n-for-wh). I am wondering how it is possible to construct such a function. I would start by saying $g(x) = f(x)-f(x+a) \neq 0$ for all $x$ in the domain and then doing casework on the values of $g(x)$. But this unlike the last question doesn't have a nice casework for the values of $g(x)$ so I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: try a function of the form $\cos(2\pi x/a) + mx$ for a well-chosen $m$.

Comment: We must have $1 = \cos{2\pi/a}+m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $ n $ be the largest integer such that $ na < 1 $.

Let $ g $ be any continuous function on $ [0, a] $ such that

$$ g(0) =  0 $$
$$ g(1-na) = -n $$
$$ g(a) = 1 $$

Then choose $ f(ka+x) = g(x) + k $ for $ k \in \mathbb{N}, x \in [0,a) $

Edit: I drew a picture of $ f $:

[image: ms paint drawing of f]

Basically, $ f $ is found by first setting $ f(x+a) = f(x) + 1$, with $ f(0) = f(1) = 0 $.  This gives you all the points in the above drawing.  Then choose a continuous $ g $ on the first 3 points, copy it and translate it by $ (a,1) $  a bunch of times to obtain $ f $.

Comment: How does $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$ here?

Comment: @user19405892 $ f(x + a) = f(x) + 1 $

Comment: What was the point of saying $g(1-na) = -n$?

Comment: @user19405892 This gives $ f(1) = f(1-na) + n = g(1-na) + n = -n + n = 0 $

Comment: Why did you define $n$ to be the largest integer such that $na < 1$? Was that really necessary?

Comment: @user19405892 I added a picture to illustrate.  $ n $ is chosen to be the largest integer so that $ 1-na $ is in the domain of $ g $.

Comment: Could you have picked $n$ differently?